# What code is faster?

Tags: c, performance, optimization

We have the following 2 snippets of code in c that do the same task.

***CODE #1:***

```
int b = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    if (x1 == x0[i])
    {
        if (y1 == y0[i])
        {
           b = 1;
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

***CODE #2:***

```
int b = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    if (x1 == x0[i] && y1 == y0[i])
    {
        b = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

What faster ***CODE #1*** or ***CODE #2***?
I really searched answer in the internet but did not find anything.

Comment: So why should we do your homework? Profile/benchmark, read the machine/assembler code counting cycles.

Comment: It depends on how the universe feels that day. Pick the one that makes most sense for the situation.

Comment: It's not my homework. I really searched answer in the internet but did not find anything.

Comment: They are THE SAME. Equal speed. You may look in disassembly to see for differences.

Comment: Both  codes  are identical. See assembly codes of them for further details. Or just read about short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: Definition of homework: "work or study done in preparation for a certain event or situation." in this case the preparation is for asking a question. Questions which ask "which is faster" are always solved by just doing a benchmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**None!**

They are both the same code.
They are written differently, but take the exact same instructions and comparisons to achieve the result, therefore, they are the same.
So, none of them is faster than the other.

Comment: ...assuming any reasonably modern optimizing compiler that can see that they are identical.

Comment: Actually no, even a not optimized compiler/interpreter would end up with  f(n) = O(n) and will execute the same number of iterations given the same input. Even if there is a difference of +/- 1 instruction or so, is still a constant K that will not affect the performance in any way.